# Getting mean values from multiple extracted layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

Bit of a novice in using ArcGIS

I've used "Extract by Mask" -> Batch to get multiple layers clipped to a catchment area I have drawn as polygons.

Is there a way to get the mean values for each of the extracted layers at once?

Without having to go through each one individually?

At the moment I'm going through the properties of each individual created layer and getting the mean value from there. The issue is that I have to do hundreds of these.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "Get Raster Properties" tool http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-raster-properties.htm  You could easily set up a loop in Python or Model Builder.

Comment: Thanks for your help
After a couple of hours I was finally able to get it working.. the only issue now is getting the values from "Collect Values" into a spreadsheet.. 

Any ideas?

Comment: @Olly if this answer helped you solve your problem you should accept it.  It appears that you now have a second question, but to get an answer for that you should compose another question on this site.